# Multi Input Python Toolbox in Arcgis

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, multi-values

I use Python toolbox in arcgis, it is possible to add a multiple input file table?

[image: Example]

And is possible to filter input files allowed by extension?

Comment: I think there should be documentation on using multivalue lists in Python toolboxes in the help for ArcGIS.  If you found some, then where precisely are you stuck?  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to supply more details.

Comment: Thankyou for answer, today I watched but I didn't find nothing, if I will find something i surely write here my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a parameter (input box) accept multiple values by setting the `multiValue` property to True.

File type filters can be added by setting the `filter.list` property to a list of accepted file types.

```py
def getParameterInfo(self):
    # Files
    params = arcpy.Parameter()
    params.name = u'Files'
    params.displayName = u'Files'
    params.parameterType = 'Required'
    params.direction = 'Input'
    params.datatype = u'DEFile'

    params.multiValue = True # Set this to accept Multiple Values

    params.filter.list = ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf'] # Set this to filter input filetypes by extension

    return [params]
```

Here are the results from using the above `getParameterInfo()` properties to limit my file types to JPG, PNG, and PDF:

Without filter
[image]

With filter
[image]

Filtered files added to tool
[image]

For more info see [Creating multivalue parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#GUID-9E1F9F7C-7327-469B-9748-B4B3DBF3736E) and [Applying filters to a parameter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#GUID-3CB5FAF4-43DD-4C84-8AFE-08039A72B3E0) on the ArcGIS for Desktop help site.